# How to set word separator chars

Tags: notepad++

In my Notepad++ (v6.6.3), '.' is recognized as word boundary but '_' is not, such that 'a_b' is recognized as 1 word but 'a.b' as 2 (when double clique). How can I define myself for the word boundary? For example I want 'a.b' is to be recognized as a single word.

Comment: i don't think you can. because numbers+letters+underscore are the components of a word. hence '_' is not recognized as word boundary

Comment: According to [this page](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/languages/user-defined-languages) it should be the role of operators in user defined languages, but it doesn't seem to be working for underscore.

Comment: correct link for @bonob's comment - http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files#How_to_install_user_defined_language_files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SynWrite editor (not N++) has option "Word chars" for this, for any lexer.

[image: Dialog]

Answer (score 4):

Notepad++ has an option for that since at least v7.5.9 (I don’t know when it was introduced).

Go to `Settings`⇒`Preferences…` and then choose `Delimiter`. Change the toggle to `Add your character as part of word` and enter '.' (without quotes) there.

[image: Word delimiter option in Notepad++ v7.5.9]